# Using an routed IPv6 prefix as dummy interfaces

Tags: networkmanager, ipv6

I recently had to change dedicated server hosts from "ReliableSite" to "Psychz". When I asked for my ARIN IPv6 allocation to be announcd, Psychz has given it as a "routed" block, assuming my server will be used as a "router".

To clarify, say I had 123::/48 from ARIN, instead of using 123::/48 on the server's interface directly in a "bridged" configuration, I got 123::/48 routed via a Psychz-provided 234::567 IPv6 address.

I tried creating a dummy interface on openSUSE and putting in my 123::/48 IPv6 settings, but I was not able to access it from outside. Rocky Linux and FreeBSD also had similar issues.

Is there a correct way to use a routed IPv6 block on a Linux server if I'm just using the IP addresses on the server itself?

Answer (score 0):

"Routed" only means that the *upstream* will route the entire prefix to you (using you as the "next hop" gateway, as opposed to ARP'ing for the addresses directly). Once those packets are delivered to you it doesn't matter what you do with them – the upstream doesn't care whether your server handles them as their own addresses or whether it forwards them somewhere else, *and* your own server doesn't really care whether those packets arrived thanks to ARP/ND or thanks to a route.

In other words, configuring the address on dummy0 (or even on 'lo') should be good enough. Though on Linux you will most likely need to enable **`net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding`** via sysctl, even though you're not *really* forwarding the packets anywhere, but just the fact that they're being sent on an address that's on an interface different than the inbound interface appears to require IP forwarding to be active.

Configuring the addresses as /128's on your physical Ethernet interface is also an option, and might avoid the above issue. (Yes, /128's, not /48's.)

Before everything, though, do a `tcpdump -n -i eth0 "net 123::/48"` and make sure you *are* in fact receiving packets from your upstream like you should. (If you got your own prefix from ARIN, I assume you're running BGP; make sure the session is up.)

(Just in case, also run the tcpdump on `-i all` to check whether you might be accidentally routing *your* packets somewhere else than the correct gateway. Take a look at your routing table; make sure the BGP daemon is able to resolve the next hop and isn't just showing "…via unreachable" for everything.)

---

If you only want to use individual addresses (without setting up a subnet that's shared with other hosts), it would be much more appropriate to configure the address on dummy0 as an `/128`, although it doesn't matter *much,* but a /48 is just weird. (You have a /48 prefix but that doesn't mean you must necessarily have a /48 subnet.)

(Or, well, *at least* configure it as a /64. Configuring a whole /48 directly on an interface is 1) a bit weird and 2) may cause problems later, whenever you *do* decide to route some smaller chunks somewhere else.)